# mongodb why we are using cors for server and client

Tags: mongodb, frontend, backend

why we use cors in for client and server?

why we use express in MongoDB?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

we use cors to allow http request to specifiq domain and pass headers and meta information.
MongoDB is no-sql data base and schema genarator for node js and express js.It helps to connect database to the server.